# HTML Checkbox, Show current value 1/0 from server db, user check/uncheck and update db

Tags: html, mysql, checkbox

**Background** - I have a RPI with several IR Beams, PIRs and reed switches around the house connected. A Python script monitors the states of pins and announces audibly via a wireless baby monitor if there is a trigger. There is a bank of toggle switches attached to the I/O pins to disable individual zones or change behavior like send sms or email video grabs via the Python script. The Pi is also a LAMP server and the Python script logs events in MySQL. The logs can be viewed via web browser.

**My aim** is to remove the bank of toggle switches and replace with check boxes in a web form, updating values 0 or 1 in db which then the Python script will use. I have been putting together a single example code to get it working before I expand it to the dozen or so values I want to control.

What I am trying to do with the code below is upon opening the webpage have the checkbox display current db value and if the user checks/unchecks the box and hits submit then the db is updated and the page refreshes to the up to date information. My code doesn't quite behave as I want as it only returns a zero to the database regardless of the state of the checkbox when the "submit" button is activated.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> checkbox wip</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>

<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "Monitor";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$thesql = "SELECT event FROM sw_sleep ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $thesql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$SSwA = $row_result['event'];


mysqli_close($conn); 

?>
<form action="update.php">
Sleep<input type="checkbox" id="sleepstat" name= "sleepstat1" value="1">    <br/>

<script>
   document.getElementById("sleepstat").checked = <?php echo $SSwA?>;
</script>


<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is update.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "Monitor";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$val = $_POST['sleepstat1'];
$sql="INSERT INTO sw_sleep (event) VALUES ('$val')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


mysqli_close($conn);

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: I think it is resolved, modified form element line to `<form action="update.php" method="post">` and now seems to work as planned.